# date validation pseudocode to javascript

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

I am having trouble converting this pseudocode statement to javascript i am new to javascript and i am confused on labling the string and i want to make sure i am on the right track

```
// Date validation function  
Function Boolean isValidDateFormat(String str)  
// Declare variables  
Declare String mm, dd, yyyy // month, day, year  
Declare Boolean result = True // valid date format  
// Check that length of string is 10  
If length(str) != 10 Then  
result = False  
End If  
// Check that third and sixth characters are slashes  
If substring(str,2,1) != "/" Or  
substring(str,5,1) != "/" Then  
result = False  
End If  
// Separate string into parts  
// Check that all entries are numeric  
mm = substring(str,0,2) // month  
dd = substring(str,3,2) // day  
yyyy = substring(str,6,4) // year  
If Not isNumeric(mm) Or Not isNumeric(dd)  
Or Not isNumeric(yyyy) Then  
result = False  
End If  
// Check that month is between 1 and 12  
// and day is between 1 and 31  
If (mm < 1 Or mm > 12) Or (dd < 1 Or dd > 31) Then  
result = False  
End If  
Return result  
End Function
```

this is my javascript translation

```
function isValidDateFormat(String str){      
   return false;    
if (str.length <10) 
  return false;   
 dd= substr[0];            
  mm= substr[3];    
   yyyy=  substr[6];   
if substr [2]!= "/";  
   substr [5]!= "/";  
 return false;  

if (mm < 1 || mm > 12)   
   return false;  
else if (dd < 1 || dd> 31)   
  return false;
```

Comment: There are several problems, including syntax, but focus on this one first: this function does nothing, because the first thing it does is "return false".

Comment: `String str` is not valid JavaScript. It should just be `str`.

Comment: You have a lot of very basic errors in there, I'd suggest you do some reading on JavaScript first. You should also note that this is a very simple validator; it will pass the 31st of February as valid, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function:

```js
function isValidDateFormat(str){
  var mm, dd, yyyy;
  if(str.length != 10){
    return false;
  }
  if(str.charAt(2) != "/" || str.charAt(5) != "/"){
    return false;
  }
  mm = str.substring(0,2);
  dd = str.substring(3,5);
  yyyy = str.substring(6,10);
  if(parseInt(mm) != parseInt(mm) ||
     parseInt(dd) != parseInt(dd) ||
     parseInt(yyyy) != parseInt(yyyy) ||
     parseFloat(yyyy) % 1 != 0){
    return false;
  } 
  if(parseInt(mm) < 1 || 
     parseInt(mm) > 12 || 
     parseInt(dd) < 1 || 
     parseInt(dd) > 31){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

console.log("is foobarbaz valid? " + isValidDateFormat("foobarbaz"));
console.log("is 09-21-1989 valid? " + isValidDateFormat("09-21-1989"));
console.log("is 88/88/8888 valid? " + isValidDateFormat("88/88/8888"));
console.log("is 09/21/19.9 valid? " + isValidDateFormat("09/21/19.9"));
console.log("is 04/12/1967 valid? " + isValidDateFormat("04/12/1967"));
```

There are different ways to check if a string contains a number, and here I'm using `a != a` to catch a NaN.

**Note**: this will return true with your original pseudocode:

```
 console.log(isValidDateFormat("09/21/19.9"));
```

So, you have to change the code to check if the string contains *only digits* (because, after all, 19.9 is a number...). One way to do that is check for the remainder:

```
parseFloat(yyyy) % 1 != 0
```